# Tcl syntax explanation

Tags: syntax, tcl

Tcl code:

```
for {local i 0 } { $i < $bsLen } { incr i } {
    local topb [bs rhex $bsStream 1]
    local botb [bs rhex $bsStream 1]
    local hexStr [strcat $hexStr $topb $botb ]
}
```

What are some documents that can help to explain the above syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Only [`for`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/for.html) and [`incr`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/incr.html) are standard Tcl commands in that sample. If you know C or Java or C#, you'll probably be able to guess what those do without too much difficulty; the syntax is a little different but not very.

The other commands are these, but I know not who defines them:

- `local` — appears to be setting a local variable. What's wrong with using [`set`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/set.html)? I don't know…
- `bs` — specifically `bs rhex`, and it appears to be getting a value (in hex?) from a stream (named in the `bsStream` variable). ***This one is totally guesswork.***
- `strcat` — I'd guess this is doing string concatenation of its arguments, as it has the name of a standard C function that does that (doing anything else would be *weird* and designed to trip its own programmer up).

That last line would be more conventionally written:

```
append hexStr $topb $botb
```

as the [`append`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/append.html) command is optimised (in its memory management, which tends to dominate these sorts of things) for the building-a-string-piecemeal case. In particular, it doesn't demonstrate quadratic [Shlemiel the painter misbehaviour](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing like the local standard keyword in Tcl.

```
for {set i 0 } { $i < $bsLen } { incr i } {
    set topb [bs rhex $bsStream 1]
    set botb [bs rhex $bsStream 1]
    sethexStr [strcat $hexStr $topb $botb ]
}
```

for {initialize} {condition_check} {inclriment} {body to execute}